# media player - pausing on second audio throws exception

Tags: java, android

I am using hourglass library for a countdown. Lets say 5 minutes. During that time i am playing the same 5 audio files over and over. This is working great. The problem is with the pause. When its on the first audio. It pauses and resumes just fine. After it gets to the next song, and i pause it, it throws a IllegalStateException.

The code is a bit ugly. In onCompletion it keeps playing the files until it gets to the end. Then i call playAudio() and the cycle starts over until the hour glass has reached zero.

**pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()** is a floating action button and i toggle between pause icon and play icon

**Java Class code**

```
    tracks[0] = R.raw.audio0;
    tracks[1] = R.raw.audio1;
    tracks[2] = R.raw.audio2;
    tracks[3] = R.raw.audio3;
    tracks[4] = R.raw.audio4;

    countDown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCountdown);
    cancel = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.cancelMeditation);
    pause = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.pauseMeditation);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    check = intent.getIntExtra("DURATION", -1);
    milliseconds = check * 60000;



    countDown.setText("" + String.format("%d min",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds)));


    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(hourglass == null){
                startTimer(milliseconds);
                currentTrack = 0;
                isTimerDone = false;
                playAudio();
                pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                return;
            }
            if(hourglass.isPaused()){
                hourglass.resumeTimer();
                pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                isPaused = false;
                mediaAffyPlayer.seekTo(length);
                mediaAffyPlayer.start();

            }else if(hourglass.isRunning()){
                hourglass.pauseTimer();
                pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play1);
                isPaused = true;
                if(mediaAffyPlayer != null) {
                    mediaAffyPlayer.pause();
                    length = mediaAffyPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                }

            } else{
                startTimer(milliseconds);
                playAudio();
            }

        }
    });


    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

}


public void startTimer(long milliseconds){
    hourglass = new Hourglass(milliseconds, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTimerTick(long timeRemaining) {

            countDown.setText("" + String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeRemaining),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeRemaining) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeRemaining))));
            if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeRemaining) ==0){
                return;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimerFinish() {
            isTimerDone = true;
        }
    };

    hourglass.startTimer();

}


private void playAudio(){

    if(mediaAffyPlayer == null){
        mediaAffyPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), tracks[0]);
        mediaAffyPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaAffyPlayer.start();
        isPaused = false;
        return;
    }
    if(mediaAffyPlayer != null) {
        mediaAffyPlayer.release();
        mediaAffyPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), tracks[0]);
        mediaAffyPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        isPaused = false;
        mediaAffyPlayer.start();
    }


    mediaAffyPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}


public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {


    if (currentTrack < tracks.length - 1) {

        if(isTimerDone){
            countDown.setText("" + String.format("%d min",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds)));
            pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play1);
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer=null;
            hourglass = null;
            return;
        }

        currentTrack++;
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), tracks[currentTrack]);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(ShowMeditationActivity.this);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    } else {
        if(!isTimerDone){
            currentTrack = 0;
            playAudio();
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException
 at android.media.MediaPlayer._pause(Native Method)
 at android.media.MediaPlayer.pause(MediaPlayer.java:1512)
```

Which throws it at  mediaAffyPlayer.pause(); in hourglass.isRunning()

I know the code is ugly, but I just think that when it plays the second track the media player object has changed and thats why it throws error. I just dont know how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated as i already burned through many hours trying to fix it.
Thanks

**EDIT**  **I fixed the issue.**

I commented out the code in OnCompletion that created and played the mediaplayer. I called playAudio() and stuck the code in there.

```
     private void playAudio(){

    if(mediaAffyPlayer == null){
        mediaAffyPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), tracks[0]);
        mediaAffyPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaAffyPlayer.start();
        isPaused = false;
        return;
    }
    if(mediaAffyPlayer != null) {
        currentTrack++;
        mediaAffyPlayer.release();
        mediaAffyPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), tracks[currentTrack]);
        mediaAffyPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(ShowMeditationActivity.this);
        mediaAffyPlayer.start();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with `isPaused()` code

try with this!!

```
 try{
    if (mediaAffyPlayer.isPlaying()) {
      mediaAffyPlayer.pause();
}
}catch(Exception we){
    we.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: When i go to play it again i get an illegal state exception. So, its not how i am pausing or resuming. It pauses and plays as many times as i want on the first song. Its the second or third or forth one that it starts to behave weird.